# Как подключиться к MySQL базе данных, которая лежит на сервере (не локальном), через C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, sql-server

Есть база данных, которая лежит на сервере (не локальном), необходимо подключиться к ней через WPF приложение. В javaFX проблем не было, нужно было установить JDBC драйвер. Как сделать это в С#?

Я не буду использовать Azure и Microsoft SQL Server, нужно подключиться напрямую. Есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: Я понимаю разницу, вопрос исправил.

Comment: Почему у вас в тегах указана СУБД `mysql`, а в вопросе `mssql`?

Comment: Не понимаю вас, и в теге и в вопросе указана MySQL

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server - это не mysql server. Это разные СУБД.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл драйвер для С#, всё работает. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score -1):

На [metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/19.2.php) неплохо описано, как это можно сделать. Только вам нужно будет подобрать правильную строку подключения `ConnectionString`. [На этом ресурсе](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) вы можете посмотреть, какая строка подключения вам нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за ресурс.